# Azure Container Service Kubernetes: How to Change VM Size?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I would like to change the VM size of agents. I can't seem to do that from the CLI or by adjusting the Container Service. How can I change the size of the agents?

Comment: You will only be able to provision new pools (with a different VM size) once they release this feature - Q1 2019 apparently.  Manually changing the VM size is not advised.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I change the size of the agents?

We can change k8s agent via Azure portal, the agent in Azure is a VM, we should resize the VM :

[image]

[image]